# Getting GPS coordinates with GPRS/GSM module

Tags: rf, gps, gsm, gprs

I'm trying to understand if I can get GPS coordinates using only a GPRS/GSM module. Probably I can do it by triangulation using BTS on the terrain and based on the RF signal but is that possible? Where do you think I can get info to guide me in that field?

Comment: What is BTS? Yes triangulation is possible if you know the mobile phone tower locations.

Comment: [BTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_transceiver_station) is exactly what you referred. When you receive the signal from the BTS is there any field in the frame or something to read their location? Sorry for the generic questions.

Comment: I believe you will have to lookup the cell location using it's ID on the internet, if connected to. Like [here](http://www.cell2gps.com/) for example, or using Google API

Comment: hum ok. Thanks for that. But imagine if we don't know where we are How can we search for an ID? Or do you think that we can find the parameters like the ID, MCC, MNC, Network, LAC, CellID in the frame that we receive from  the GPRS data?

Comment: @scuba Yes, I believe this is the idea. I have no much experience in this kind of stuff, but you can take a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329877/how-to-properly-triangulate-gsm-cell-towers-to-get-a-location) Specifically the `AT+KCELL` command

Comment: You say GPS module, which will do as it says on the tin and give you GPS coordinates without all this faffing with cells. But see also http://opencellid.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some cellular providers that have implemented posisioning services on their networks, so you can get the latitude and longitude using some special AT commands. The problem with this option is that is very dificult to get information or support about this feature.

Comment: It's not so difficult to get that. Follow [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329877/how-to-properly-triangulate-gsm-cell-towers-to-get-a-location). It was provided by @Eugene Sh.

Comment: Thanks for the info. It's very useful.

Also, some cellular providers do these calculations and they offer an AT command, so all you have to do is to execute this AT command in  your modem and the network will answer you with your approx. location (lat and long).